# Custom controller not updating record changes

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a simple VF page that displays 4 fields from a list of OpportunityLineItems. Two of the fields are input fields.  Any changes I make do not get saved back to the original record.  What changes should I make to my controller to get this to work as intended?

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OLI_SplitQty2" id="thePage" tabStyle="Product2" sidebar="false">
<!-- Style for Page Messages -->
<style>
    .Messages { color: red; font-weight: strong;}
    .StatusPicklist { }
</style>

<!-- Javascript -->
<script>
    // Script to provide pop-up on 'Cancel' button click
    function confirmCancel() {
        var isCancel = confirm("Are you sure you wish to cancel?");
        if (isCancel) return true;

        return false;
    }
</script>

<!-- Section Header -->
<apex:sectionHeader title="Split Products by Quantity" />
<!-- Steps for the end users -->
<!--
<h1>Notes:</h1>
<ol>
    <li>Select the Product(s) you want to split and</li>
    <li>enter a quantity to split off</li>
</ol>
-->

<!-- Form with Page Blocks and Sections -->
<apex:form >
    <!-- Page Block providing the user with Editable Table -->   
    <apex:pageBlock title="Select the Product(s) you want to split by entering a Quantity to split off and a new Line Description (optional)">

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!split}" value="Split" immediate="false"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" onclick="return confirmCancel()" immediate="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:messages styleClass="Messages"/>

        <apex:pageBlockSection id="editableView" title="Opportunity Product List View" columns="1" rendered="true" collapsible="false" >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OLIs}" var="val">

                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Product Name</apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!val.ID}" >{!val.Product_Name__c}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Quantity</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!val.Quantity}" />
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Split Qty</apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!val.Split_Qty__c}" />
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Line Description</apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!val.Description}" />
                </apex:column> 

            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class OLI_SplitQty2 {

public ApexPages.StandardController sc;
public Opportunity Opp {get; set;}
public List<OpportunityLineItem> OLIlist2 {get; set;}

public OLI_SplitQty2(ApexPages.StandardController sc) { 
    getOIDQueryParameter();
    OLIlist2 = [Select Product_Name__c, ID, Quantity, Split_Qty__c, Description, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId =:Opp.Id];

}

public Boolean getOIDQueryParameter(){
    Opp = new Opportunity(id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oid'));
    return null;
}

public List<OpportunityLineItem> getOLIs() {
    List<OpportunityLineItem> OLIlist2 = [Select Product_Name__c, ID, Quantity, Split_Qty__c, Description, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId =:Opp.Id];

    return OLIlist2;
}

public PageReference split() {
    PageReference returnPage;

    update(OLIlist2);
    returnPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(Opp).view();
    returnPage.setRedirect(true);
    return returnPage;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your issue was this being used as the iterator

```
public List<OpportunityLineItem> getOLIs() {
    List<OpportunityLineItem> OLIlist2 = [Select Product_Name__c, ID, Quantity, Split_Qty__c, Description, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId =:Opp.Id];

    return OLIlist2;
}
```

and then in the `split()` method you were saving the class property `OLIlist2` which was not what was being edited on the page

Remove the above and change the VF to:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OLIlist2}" var="val">
```

And it will work. I tested it in my org.

Description: In the `getOLIs` you are populating a **local** property OLIlist2 which is NOT available outside of that method.

There is no need to have that method there as you are already populating a list in the constructor. You could have also salvaged it by modifying the method to the following:

```
public List<OpportunityLineItem> getOLIs() {
    OLIlist2 = [Select Product_Name__c, ID, Quantity, Split_Qty__c, Description, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId =:Opp.Id];

    return OLIlist2;
}
```

Which would have assigned the query to the class property

Comment: That did not help.  The records are still not updating.  Are they somehow being requeried prior to the update?

Comment: @EricSmith - Updated my answer, thanks for confirming it was not the rerender issue

Comment: Perfect - thank you.  What's a good source for newbies to wrap their head around the whole object oriented Apex structure?

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com